# How to transform a SQL query with subselects into an MDX query?

Tags: sql, oracle, mdx, mondrian

I have a database table called "tableOne". The table is connected with a cube.

The following SQL select query

```
select row_id, row_group_id, col_group_id, measure_col from tableOne where 
(row_group_id in (select row_group_id from tableOne a where row_id in ('R0020', 'R0030') and col_id = 'C0050')
or col_group_id in (select col_group_id from tableOne a where row_id in ('R0020', 'R0030') and col_id ='C0050'));
```

has to be transformed into a MDX query.

Please note:

- The columns row_id, col_id, row_group_id and col_group_id are
  dimensions.
- The column measure_col is a measure.

I’m using Mondrian and I don’t know how to convert the subselect into the MDX query.

EDIT:

This is what I got so far:

```
SELECT
{
 [Measures].[measure_col]
}
ON COLUMNS,
non empty(
 CrossJoin([ROW].[ROW].Members
,CrossJoin([COL_GROUP].[COL_GROUP].Members
,[ROW_GROUP].[ROW_GROUP].Members
)))
ON ROWS
FROM [tableOne]
WHERE (
[COL].[COL].[C0050]
)
```

Can't tell you anything else about the cube other than what I already told you.

Comment: if someone tagged a question C# and pasted a Java in and said "I need this Java code in C#" they would get massively down-voted. Do you have any mdx you have tried ? Can you show us, in more detail, the dimensions of your cube ?

Comment: Hi, updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

First may i suggest you rewrite your SQL to something like this:

```
select row_id, row_group_id, col_group_id, measure_col 
from tableOne a
where 
    exists(
        select *
        from tableOne b
        where
            row_id in ('R0020', 'R0030') and 
            col_id = 'C0050' and
            (
                a.row_group_id = b.row_group_id OR
                a.col_group_id = b.col_group_id
            )
)
```

It should remove one scan from your plan. Now the MDX part.

If it's something you want to use in a calculated measure, it would be best if you do this in SQL.

Not sure if this MDX will return the output you want.

```
WITH
SET mySet
AS
NONEMPTY (
    (
        [COL_GROUP].[COL_GROUP].Members,
        [ROW_GROUP].[ROW_GROUP].Members
    ),
    (
        {[ROW].[ROW].[R0020],[ROW].[ROW].[R0030]},
        [COL].[COL].[C0050],
        [Measures].[measure_col]
    )

)
SELECT
    {
     [Measures].[measure_col]
    }
    ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY
    CROSSJOIN(
        [ROW].[ROW].MEMBERS,
        mySet
    )
    ON ROWS
FROM [tableOne]
```

`mySet` should give you all the combinations of `COL_GROUP` and `ROW_GROUP`, that have values for `ROW` R0020 and R0030 and `COL` C0050.